# Arduino import jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arduino, esp8266

I have working code for esp8266 in which jquery is imported from the internet, but I need to import it from the downloaded file and I can't do it. When I write #include "jquery-3.5.1.min.js", it gives an error: jquery-3.5.1.min.js: No such file or directory (It also gives this error if I specify the full path). Although this file is located in the same directory as the project file. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"


const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
IPAddress apIP(172, 0, 0, 1);
DNSServer dnsServer;
ESP8266WebServer webServer(80);


String handleRoot = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>\
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Ввод:</h1>
  <input type='text' name='input' id='input' size=2 autofocus>
  <div>
  <br><button id='save_button'>Send</button>
  </div>
<script src="/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var input;
$('#save_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    input = $('#input').val();
    $.get('/send?input=' + input, function(data){
     console.log(data);
    });
  });   
</script>
</body>
</html>
)=====";

void handleSend() {
  if (webServer.arg("input")!= ""){
    Serial.println("Input is: " + webServer.arg("input"));
  }
 }


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println("Started");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
  WiFi.softAP("INFO");

  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);

  webServer.onNotFound([]() {
  webServer.send(200, "text/html", handleRoot);
  });
  webServer.on ("/send", handleSend);
  webServer.begin();
}

void loop() {
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  webServer.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript file that needs to be included in the web page you're serving. `#include` is meant to include C code in the file you're compiling. There's absolutely no way what you're trying to do here makes sense. Try reading about the ESP8266 web server and looking for other examples - read about how to write a web page and read some C tutorials to understand `#include`.

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is expecting to load the `/jquery-3.5.1.min.js` from your server(i.e. your ESP8266), in which your server doesn't serve. Giving that jQuery requires 20-30kB of memory and it is probably too slow for ESP8266 to serve it and take too much of precious memory, one quick and alternative solution is to load the jQuery directly from jquery CDN site by changing your JavaScript line to:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Please also delete the `#include "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"` from your sketch as you `#include` is for C/C++ to load modules, not design to serve a data file over Internet.

Please noted that this is a workable solution, but it is not a best practise. It is better to write pure JavaScript to handle the requests rather than depend on jQuery library which will take up about 30kB+ memory, especially for IoT application when using an MCU as a web server.